# document.getElementById('myElement').click(); not working as desired

Tags: javascript, dom, plupload

A very short summary of "why" I need this. I am using [PlUpload](http://www.plupload.com) which lets you upload files using Ajax while providing you back events like percentage, completion, etc. You instantiate the object, then call the "init" (telling it on which ID to "link to") and then add all the event listeners. Since the page which needs the object is created at run time and cannot include JS, I simply created a DIV (which I will make invisible when everything works...) in the main page with the links inside.

This is the link:

```
<a id="browse" href="javascript:;">Browse</a>
```

If I click it directly, it works.

When I create the new subpage in real-time, I want the link to be called when the user clicks on an image, like this:

```
<img onclick="document.getElementById('browse').click(); return false;" src="whatever.jpg">
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. If I use any other "clickable link" rather than the "browse", it works, so there is no apparent error in the syntax.

Please note that if I modify the link like this:

```
<a id="browse" onclick="alert('Hello'); return false;" href="javascript:;">Browse</a>
```

Then I can see the "Hello" popup when I click on the image.

I am a beginner in JS/HTML, so if this is an obvious problem... Sorry ;)
Or if you know of a better solution to the general problem (without jQuery please), I would be grateful :)

This is the init part of the PlUpload:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  browse_button: 'browse', 
  url: 'newupload.php',
});

uploader.init();
```

Comment: We need to see how the event listeners are added. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the requested "init", but as said I am using PlUpload. I have no idea how it does what it does... As said, it works if I click the link directly.

Comment: When you click that "button" you are not actually clicking that button. There is other html elements on top of it. inspect it.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry I do not understand what you mean. If I add the alert, I can see that it gets clicked, but it is not calling whatever function PlUpload associated with it. Again, if I click it with the mouse, it works. And if I change the id in the img to any other element on the page it works. And if I add the alert, I can see the alert... :(

Comment: If it is just like their demo, there is another element positioned above that button with css. Right Click on the button and inspect it with the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the  element inside  element and you can click on the image which will do the same effect.

```
<a href="..."><img src="..."></img></a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do what you say. If I put the img inside the "<a>" element, then it would not appear in the right place on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the click() method try using this:

```
$('#browse').trigger("click");
```

this should trigger the event of the link instead of listening to the event and if you dont want to use jQuery you can simply do this:

```
document.getElementById('browse').onclick();
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I tried the jQuery version, but it doesn't work either. The second one is 100% what I am doing now, what do you mean? Thank you.

Comment: the second one uses the "onclick" function, your code is calling "click"

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. Tried, and it is not calling the event :(